# How to get XY Coordinate of a text using Google image to text API?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-api, ocr, google-translate

I am trying a windows application using  **Google.Cloud.Vision.V1** I was able to extract the text and also able to translate, but my current intention is to get a XY coordinates of the text on an image, so later I can show the translated text on exact place on original image.

Can someone please advise me how can I achieve it ?

my current approach is bellow

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(JsonFilePath).CreateScoped(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultScopes);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ImageAnnotatorClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();

var image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Work Temp\image_2.JPG");
// Performs label detection on the image file
var response = client.DetectText(image); // TODO: need to get XY Coordinates of those texts
foreach (var annotation in response)
{
   if (annotation.Description != null)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);                        
     translatedText.Add(TranslateTextSample(annotation.Description, "en"));
    }
 }
 textTranslate.Lines = translatedText.ToArray();
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current solution?

Comment: @DaImTo I couldn't get the coordinates of the text on the image, but i assume I can use the vertices property of the return object

Comment: Note that the way you're creating the `ImageAnnotatorClient` can be simplified significantly: `var client = new ImageAnnotatorClientBuilder { CredentialsPath = JsonFilePath }.Build();`